# Does a scene have to be removed when changing scenes?

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, automatic-ref-counting, skscene

In sprite-kit I'm making a game that includes various levels in different scenes. Im curious if just transitioning to a scene will remove the other scene or will they continue to pile up and take up cpu usage? I'm transitioning them all in this sort of fashion.

```
let reveal = SKTransition.fade(with: UIColor.white, duration: 1.5)
let scene = level2(size: self.size)
self.view?.presentScene(scene, transition:reveal)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Good practice #1

It's usually a good practice keeping only one scene in memory while your are executing your game.

### Good practice #2

Another good practice is avoiding **strong retaining reference loops**. Specifically should not exist a descendant node of your scene with a strong reference to the scene itself.

### presentScene

That said when you invoke

```
 self.view?.presentScene(scene, transition:reveal)
```

the strong reference from the `SKView` to the scene is removed. So, if you respected the 2 assumptions above, the scene will automatically be deinitialized and removed from memory.

### Test

You can test it yourself. Just add this to your game scene

```
deinit {
    print("GameScene deinit")
}
```

This method is automatically invoked when the instance is deinitialized.

Now run

```
 self.view?.presentScene(scene, transition:reveal)
```

and look for the `"GameScene deinit"` into the log.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on what you mean by removed.  It will stop running so is removed from the views draw and update cycles. Now whether or not it gets removed from memory is up to you.  There are things called retain counts,  presenting a scene adds to the retain count,  removing removes from the retain count.  If retain count goes to zero, it deallocs.